# Use only some features (ref/cite completion) of vim-latex

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

I have been using Vim for coding LaTeX files for some time now, but did not like vim-latex at first sight and therefore never used it.

However the the project-wide(!) ref/cite completion of vim-latex seems to pretty awesome. Long story short: I would like to use this single feature, but nothing else. No  magic, no (other) mappings, nothing.

How to do that? (In a perfect world I would also like to be able to add more and more features of vim-latex as I like, just not all of them at once.    I am a creature of habit.)

Comment: Maybe consider a more light weight plugin such as https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box

Comment: @FDinoff: Oh yes, using another plugin which also has this feature could work as well. :)

Answer (score 6):

I can not answer your question regarding vim-latex (aka LaTeX-Suite), however, I can recommend two plugins that provide good label and bibliography completion:

### vimtex

Vimtex is a simple and lightweight LaTeX plugin for vim that is initially based on LaTeX-Box. The code is now very much diverged from LaTeX-Box, and the plugin is IMHO better maintained and more actively developed. *Disclaimer: vimtex is written and maintained by me.*

As for your question, vimtex supports a modular approach where you may enable/disable functionality that you want to use. If you only want the completion functionality, then you may achieve this in [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) by disabling all the other functionalities. Place the following in your `vimrc` file:

```
let g:vimtex_fold_enabled = 0
let g:vimtex_indent_enabled = 0
let g:vimtex_indent_bib_enabled = 0
let g:vimtex_labels_enabled = 0
let g:vimtex_toc_enabled = 0
let g:vimtex_mappings_enabled = 0
let g:vimtex_motion_enabled = 0
let g:vimtex_latexmk_enabled = 0
let g:vimtex_view_enabled = 0
```

Alternatively, you can disable vimtex completely and then only enable the completion:

```
let g:vimtex_enabled = 0
call vimtex#complete#init(0)
```

### LaTeX-Box

In [LaTeX-Box](https://github.com/LaTeX-Box-Team/LaTeX-Box) one can not selectively enable or disable functionality (I believe), but it is a simple and lightweight plugin with good completion functionality.

Comment: Honestly, vimtex seems to be *way* better then LaTeX-Box. I spent the last hour copying vim-latex‘ `*.latexmain` behavior, that‘s not needed here. Also you completions show `\tag{foo}` tags, that‘s also nice.

Comment: Thanks @Keba! I appreciate the feedback. Please don't hesitate to open issues if you find any bugs/have any problems/have ideas for new features.

Comment: As you may have noticed, I already did that (on github). :)